# Ansible readfile and concatenate a variable to each line

Tags: loops, ansible

Hi I  have a file with  list of filenames .I want to read each line and add a variable {{version}} to the end and pass it to another task which will download the artifact .

**MY_File**

```
cat file/branches.txt
mhr-
mtr-
tsr
```

I want to get each line add {{version}} to it

```
mhr-1.1-SNAPSHOT
mtr-1.1-SNAPSHOT
tsr-1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I couldn't get the  file names and append them. below is a failed attempt by me .

```
---
- name: get file names
  shell: echo {{item}}{{version}}
  register: result
  with_lines: cat files/branches.txt

- include_tasks: 2main.yml
  with_items: "{{result.results}}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need a new variable which contains text like `mhr-1.1-SNAPSHOT` depending on the source file. You can use `set_fact` to achieve this.

Example:

```yaml
vars:
  file_versions: []
  version: "1.1-SNAPSHOT"

tasks:
- set_fact:
    file_versions: "{{ file_versions }} + [ '{{ item }}{{ version }}' ]"
  with_lines: cat file/branches.txt
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ file_versions }}"
- include_tasks: 2main.yml
  with_items: "{{ file_versions }}"
```

Gives below `debug` output:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=mhr-1.1-SNAPSHOT) => {
    "msg": "mhr-1.1-SNAPSHOT"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=mtr-1.1-SNAPSHOT) => {
    "msg": "mtr-1.1-SNAPSHOT"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=tsr-1.1-SNAPSHOT) => {
    "msg": "tsr-1.1-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

Comment: hi seshadri_c its not iterating  the debug is printing only line one mhr-1.1-SNAPSHOT its not looping ,I tried to use loop instead of with_items but it fails

Comment: I think then the list is not getting appended. Hope the `+` part is not missed in your case. It is working for me, I have added the `debug` output in my answer.

Comment: HI i was able to create desired variable and pass it to other task sucessfully thanks a lot for you help

Comment: Good to know you figured it out. Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell:

```yaml
---
- name: append version to names found in a local text file line by line
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # This is the version we want to append
    version: 1.1-SNAPSHOT

    # This is the file on local controller containing the names
    my_file: /tmp/my_file.txt

    # This var will contain a list of each name in file with appended version
    file_version: "{{ lookup('file', my_file).splitlines() | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '\\g<1>' + version) | list }}"

 
  tasks:
    - name: Show the result
      debug:
        var: file_version

    - name: Loop on var with an include (the passed var is item in this case)
      include_tasks: some_other_tasks_working_on_item.yml
      loop: "{{ file_version }}"
```